# How to match from 1 to 12. given Version/13.1.2

Tags: regex, digits

I can not get the correct match to Version/13, I want to cover just from Version 1 to Version/12 and skip the versions 13....20 etc...

I have tried with  `Version\/([0-9]?[0-2]?){1}`. It is a part of the larger regex that looks like `^((?!chrome|android|iphone|ipad).)*safari|Version\/([0-9]?[0-2]?){1}`.

Comment: Try `\bVersion\/([1-9]|1[0-3])\b`, see https://regex101.com/r/1GP73D/1

Comment: it does not work https://regexr.com/4ga8v it covers Version/1

Comment: What do you mean by "cover"? If "match", `\bVersion\/([1-9]|1[0-2])\b` should match `Version/1` to `Version/12`, see https://regex101.com/r/1GP73D/2. BTW, you are not using `\b` word boundary in your demo.

Comment: See `^((?!chrome|android|iphone|ipad).)*safari|\bVersion\/([1-9]|1[0-2])\b` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/1GP73D/5)) - is it working as expected?

Comment: Also, please put the actual regex you have into the question body.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
^((?!chrome|android|iphone|ipad).)*safari|\bVersion\/([1-9]|1[0-2])\b
                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1GP73D/5)

The added alternative is `\bVersion\/([1-9]|1[0-2])\b`:

- `\bVersion` - a whole word `Version`
- `\/` - a `/` char (needs escaping only if used in a regex literal with `/` as regex delimiters)
- `([1-9]|1[0-2])` - a number from `1` to `12`
- `\b` - a word boundary.

The entire [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E((%3F!chrome%7Candroid%7Ciphone%7Cipad).)*safari%7C%5CbVersion%2F(%5B1-9%5D%7C1%5B0-2%5D)%5Cb):

[image]